# Capitalizing The First Letter Of Each Word In Attribute Field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

Does anyone know of a way to capitalize the first letter of each word in a field in an attribute table?  I am doing this in QGIS.  I know of field calculations to change all the words to Lower or Upper, but I would like to be able to have the first letter Capitalized of each word, and the remaining letters lower cased.  I know how to do this manually, but I am looking for an automated way.  Similar to the Proper command in Excel.

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the python field calculator:

[http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Using_Python_to_calculate_attribute_values_with_'fieldpyculator'](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Using_Python_to_calculate_attribute_values_with_%27fieldpyculator%27)

You should be able to us the .title() method on your strings:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728655/python-titlecase-a-string-with-exceptions

**Edit:**

Assuming the attribute field you want to change is "FIELD", the sintax to use is:

```
value = <FIELD>.title()
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be on the right track, but I am a little confused with the syntax.  From reading the links and others, I assumed it would be: value = str.Title( <BLD_NAME> ) but that gives a syntax error.  Is there something else I need to add before str?

Comment: Take a look into my Edit, in your especific case, it will be:
value = <BLD_NAME>.title()
Notice that Python is case sensitive. Also, title() is not a function but a method of the class string, that's why the syntax is string.title()

Answer (score 11):

The feature is already integrated at Qgis.

The following screen shot is from version QGis 1.9-Master, but most probably exists in previous versions as well.

[image]

Comment: I am using 1.8.0 and it is not available.