# Capitalizing The First Letter Of Each Word In Attribute Field QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I have tried capitalizing the first letter of each string in my field/column called "COMMUNITY" by referencing this post:

[Capitalizing The First Letter Of Each Word In Attribute Field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58028/capitalizing-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-attribute-field)

Particularly:     `value = <COMMUNITY>.title()`

I get an *Expression is invalid* output. What am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the following syntax.

`title('yourstring')`

or

```
title("yourfield")
```

The answer to that question is talking about using a 3rd party plugin (not sure why really)

Comment: How does one capitalize the first letter of every string in a particular field? title('xyz') would specifically create Xyz for that string. But, for every string in a field?